# Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined (Excel-VBA with dll)

Tags: vba, dll, dllimport

I am trying to access dll functions via Excel-VBA.
I have implemented VBA code to select and load the dll at runtime, and then call a function from dll.

Following is my VBA code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim lb As Long, sf As Long, cs As Long, wd As Long, rd As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FreeLibrary Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hLibModule As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function LoadLibrary Lib "kernel32" Alias "LoadLibraryA" (ByVal lpLibFileName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetProcAddress Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hModule As Long, ByVal lpProcName As String) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallWindowProc Lib "user32" Alias "CallWindowProcA" (ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Any, ByVal wParam As Any, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Sub LinkToDll()
    Dim path As String, default As String
    Dim retValue As Long, hWnd As Long
    Dim portNum As String
    MsgBox "Select .dll file from next window"
    
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select .dll file"
        If .Show = True Then
            path = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    MsgBox path
    lb = LoadLibrary(path)
End Sub

Function SomeFunctionOnWorksheet(dArg As Double) As Integer
    SomeFunctionOnWorksheet = SomeFunction(dArg)
End Function

Sub useSomeFunctionInVBA()
    MsgBox SomeFunction(10)
End Sub
```

Following is my dll function:

```cpp
// a sample exported function
DLL_EXPORT int __stdcall SomeFunction(const double somedouble)
{
    //MessageBoxA(0, somedouble, "DLL Message", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    return (23 + somedouble);
}

// my practice function
DLL_EXPORT BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    static HANDLE hThread;
    //hThisModule = hinstDLL;
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, mainThread, 0, 0, 0);
            break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

I have added two buttons in the excel sheet, one for selecting the dll, and another for calling the `SomeFunction` from dll.

I am able to load the dll, however, when I press the button to call the dll function, I get Compile error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which line is raising the error? are you on Office 64 bit?

Comment: When you run the code you get a "compile error"? Nah!

Comment: @RicardoDiaz: Yes, i am using Office64

Comment: @StureS: I do not get compile error on running the code. That's not what i said. I get compile error when i try to access the function "SomeFunction" in dll.

Comment: Loading a module with `LoadLibrary` (which you have `Declare`d wrong, it should be crashing; same for the other three `Declare`d functions) does not magically import all its exported functions into VBA namespace for VBA to easily call. You must declare your `SomeFunction` in the exact same way you have declared `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: @Sandrocottus: The compiler does not "call" any dll function, the compiler resolves the addresses needed to access the functions. You mix things up!

Comment: Yes, i got it. Thanks a ton! :-)